# WeChat doesn't generate notification sounds on my iphone

Tags: iphone, notifications

I've been using the WeChat app which often fails to generate a notification sound when new messages are received. I've noticed that it's a common problem and [switching off the battery saver mode doesn't necessarily solve it](https://www.reddit.com/r/GooglePixel/comments/ajwzgd/not_getting_wechat_notifications/). Does anyone know how to fix this problem on iphone? I'm using iphone 7 iOS 12.1.4

Comment: The linked discussion points to troubleshooting the issue on an Android phone. Please edit your question to include the version of iOS and which iPhone you have. And if you don't have an iPhone you will need to ask this question elsewhere, like here: https://android.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Maybe your screen was on when you receive the message. Also check Notification settings and sound settings as the first step.

Comment: @ankii I checked those settings and they seemed normal

Comment: WeChat might have some internal settings, maybe mute-like options etc. Please post screenshots of all the relevant settings.

Comment: @SteveChambers Just updated my question. Yes I have an iphone but this problem seems to be present on both iphone and Android. So I suppose there should be some fix from WeChat's end instead of system setting, maybe

Comment: @Dr_Hope, if it is present on both mobile platforms then, yes, I would say the issue is with WeChat and not the platform it is on. Maybe there is a simple solution or a hidden setting but I would bet that the solution is much more likely to be found with their tech support.

Comment: @SteveChambers  I'm getting an Android phone tomorrow and will let you know whether it's iphone-specific

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your ringer is on, as push notifications only sound if the ringer is on. To toggle the ringer, use your side switch.